# Convert two's complement hex number to boost::multiprecision::int256_t

Tags: c++, boost, hex, boost-multiprecision

I'm trying to get boost::multiprecision to parse a negative (two's complement) hex number:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::string hex_str = "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb2e";
  boost::multiprecision::int256_t signed_int(hex_str);

  std::cout << signed_int << std::endl;

}
```

I expect this to output -1234. Unfortunately, it outputs 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129638702

Parsing an unsigned hex number works fine.

How can I get int256_t to interpret a hex number as a negative two's complement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hex conversion constructor simply doesn't parse a sign. Likewise, std::cout will refuse to print hex numbers if they're negative, and indeed `.str(..., std::ios::hex)` will throw an `runtime_error` exception ("Base 8 or 16 printing of negative numbers is not supported").

So you have to make it work manually, like

```
UInt uval(str);
Int  val;

if (/*signbit =*/uval >> 255) {
    // manual two's complement
    val = ~uval + 1;
    val.backend().sign(true);
} else {
    val = uval.convert_to<boost::multiprecision::int256_t>();
}
```

Here's a test program verifying all the edge cases:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6b09e62523fd997)**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_literals;
using UInt = boost::multiprecision::uint256_t;
using Int  = boost::multiprecision::int256_t;

int main()
{
    static const auto min = -Int(UInt(1) << 255);
    static const auto max = Int(UInt(1) << 255 - 1);
    static const auto dec = std::ios::dec;
    static const auto hex = std::ios::hex | std::ios::showbase;

    struct {
        std::string_view caption;
        Int              expected;
        std::string      str;
    } testcases[] = {
        // clang-format off
        {"zero", 0, Int{0}.str(0, dec),},
        {"zero", 0, Int{0}.str(0, hex),},
        //
        {"one", 1, Int{1}.str(0, dec),},
        {"one", 1, Int{1}.str(0, hex),},
        //
        {"negone", -1, Int{-1}.str(0, dec),},
        {"negone", -1, "0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"s,},
        //
        {"min", min, (min).str(0, dec),},
        {"min", min, "0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"s,},
        //
        {"min+1", min+1, (min + 1).str(0, dec),},
        {"min+1", min+1, "0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"s,},
        //
        {"max-1", max-1, (max - 1).str(0, dec),},
        {"max-1", max-1, (max - 1).str(0, hex),},
        //
        {"max", max, (max).str(0, dec),},
        {"max", max, (max).str(0, hex),},
        // question case
        {"question", -1234, "-1234"s,},
        {"question", -1234, "0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb2e"s,},
        // clang-format on
    };

    for (auto [caption, expected, str] : testcases) {
        std::cout << " ---- " << caption << ":\t\t" << str << "\n";

        UInt uval(str);
        Int  val;

        if (/*signbit =*/uval >> 255) {
            // manual two's complement
            val = ~uval + 1;
            val.backend().sign(true);
        } else {
            val = uval.convert_to<boost::multiprecision::int256_t>();
        }

        std::cout << "Expected? " << std::boolalpha
                  << (expected == val ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED") << "\t";

        std::cout << std::dec << val;
        if (val.sign() >= 0) // negative no hex
            std::cout << " (" << std::hex << std::showbase << val << ")";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 ---- zero:     0
Expected? SUCCESS   0 (0x0)
 ---- zero:     0x0
Expected? SUCCESS   0 (0x0)
 ---- one:      1
Expected? SUCCESS   1 (0x1)
 ---- one:      0x1
Expected? SUCCESS   1 (0x1)
 ---- negone:       -1
Expected? SUCCESS   -1
 ---- negone:       0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Expected? SUCCESS   -1
 ---- min:      -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
Expected? SUCCESS   -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
 ---- min:      0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Expected? SUCCESS   -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
 ---- min+1:        -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967
Expected? SUCCESS   -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967
 ---- min+1:        0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
Expected? SUCCESS   -57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967
 ---- max-1:        28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409983
Expected? SUCCESS   28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409983 (0x3fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
 ---- max-1:        0x3fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Expected? SUCCESS   28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409983 (0x3fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
 ---- max:      28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409984
Expected? SUCCESS   28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409984 (0x4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
 ---- max:      0x4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Expected? SUCCESS   28948022309329048855892746252171976963317496166410141009864396001978282409984 (0x4000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
 ---- question:     -1234
Expected? SUCCESS   -1234
 ---- question:     0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffb2e
Expected? SUCCESS   -1234
```

#### PS

As a side-note, apparently numeric limits cannot be  trusted, so I sidestepped them above.

```
assert(std::numeric_limits<UInt>::max() != std::numeric_limits<Int>::max());
assert(std::numeric_limits<UInt>::min() != std::numeric_limits<Int>::min());
```

Comment: on `PS`: the numeric limits is sort of documented in the cpp_int documentation: [...] slightly different from a 2's complement fundamental (built-in) type as the minimum and maximum values are identical (apart from the sign), [...]